# Como puedo obetener un valor almacenado en una variable de tipo objeto en JAVA, al imprimir en un void distinto aparece como null

Tags: java, objeto, get, null

> Estoy trantando de obtener el valor almacenado en la varibale Material_conductor, la cual es un objeto, pero cuando la llamo con el metodo get para usarla en fuera del propio metodo que la contine me aparece como si estuviera nula, abajo dejo el codigo que estoy empleando, la objetivo es usar el valor obtenido para hacer un filtro en una base de datos, para mostrar en un formulario los resultados obtenidos.

> #Paquete Modelo:

---

````
```public class Entradas {
    private double temp_conductor;
    private String material_conductor;
    private String tipo_conductor;
    private Double ampacidad;
    private Double resistencia;
    private Double reactancia;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formulario form=new Formulario();
        form.setVisible(true);
        form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public String getMaterial_conductor() {
        return material_conductor;
    }

    public void setMaterial_conductor(String material_conductor) {
        this.material_conductor = material_conductor; ```
````

> #Paquete EntradasControler para buscar desde una base de datos:

---

````
``` public class EntradasControler {
    
      public boolean buscar(Entradas datos, String calibrefiltrar, String materialfiltrar){
      boolean respuesta=false;
      try {
          Connection con=Conexion.conectar();
        //Consultar en la BBDD
        String sql="SELECT * FROM tabla_caracteristicas_conductores WHERE calibre=? AND material=?";
        ResultSet rs;
         PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        try(con;ps) {
              
               ps.setString(1, calibrefiltrar);
               ps.setString(2, materialfiltrar);
               //ps sentencia preparada y se ejetucta la consulta en sl string sql
               
               rs=ps.executeQuery();
               if(rs.next()){
                   datos.setCalibre(rs.getString("calibre"));
                   datos.setAmpacidad(rs.getDouble("ampacidad"));
                   datos.setResistencia(rs.getDouble("resistencia"));
                   datos.setReactancia(rs.getDouble("reactancia"));

                   respuesta=true;
      } 
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

      }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      
      }
      return respuesta;
}
}```
````

> #asigno el valor desde un combobox, depenciendo de lo que escoja el usuario se le asigna un valor a la temperatura, al material y al tipo de conductor:

---

````
```private void txtlistatipodeconductorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
Entradas datos=new Entradas();
    if(txtlistatipodeconductor.getSelectedItem().equals("75°C - Monopolar - Cu")){
            datos.setTemp_conductor(75);
            datos.setMaterial_conductor("Cu");
            datos.setTipo_conductor("Monopolar");
            //System.out.println(datos.getMaterial_conductor());
            }
            else if(txtlistatipodeconductor.getSelectedItem().equals("90°C - Monopolar - Cu")){
            datos.setTemp_conductor(90);
            datos.setMaterial_conductor("Cu");
            datos.setTipo_conductor("Monopolar");
            }
            else{
            datos.setTemp_conductor(75);
            datos.setMaterial_conductor("Cu");
            datos.setTipo_conductor("Multiconductor");
            }
}```
````

> #llamo al metodo consultar desde un combobox, siempre que escaja el calibre del conductor se debe ejecurar el metodo consultar:#

````
```private void txtcalibreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        consultar();
}```

>#se ejecuta el metodo consultar que debe obtener los datos del material y otros parametros:#
```    private void consultar(){
        
        Entradas datos=new Entradas();
             
        EntradasControler controler=new EntradasControler();
        
        System.out.println(datos.getMaterial_conductor());
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(datos.getMaterial_conductor()));
        
        if(controler.buscar(datos,String.valueOf(txtcalibre.getSelectedItem()),datos.getMaterial_conductor())){

        txtampacidad.setText(String.valueOf(datos.getAmpacidad()));
        txtresistencia.setText(String.valueOf(datos.getResistencia()));
        txtreactancia.setText(String.valueOf(datos.getReactancia()));
        }
        else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Calibre no encontrado"); 
        }
    }```
````

Comment: no deberias crear un nuevo objeto de tipo Entradas dentro de tu método consultar ya que a ese objeto no le as asignado ningún valor, que le hayas nombrado como el otro objeto datos,no significa que sean iguales es otra `instancia`,tu metodo consultar deberia recibir como parametro un objeto de tipo Entrada,asi al pasarle el primer objeto creado te imprimira los datos que requieres

Comment: El código que muestras en la pregunta está de una forma muy confusa. ¿Desde  dónde llamas a `consultar()`? ¿Ese método es parte de una clase? ¿De qué clase? Aparte de eso, como te ha indicado @Dramaturgo, no debes crear una nueva instancia de `Entradas` en el método `consultar()`. Por favor, pon el código completo como lo tienes.

Comment: Acabo de agregar mas detalle al codigo.

Comment: ya modifique el metodo para que reciba un objeto de tipo Entradas, pero como llamo al metodo consultar desde otro metodo ingresando el parametro Material_conductor?